# Eclipse: Add Command-Line Args to an OS X .app Directory

Tags: eclipse, macos, command-line

Is it possible to add custom command-line arguments to an Eclipse .app folder? In my particular case, I'm working with ZendStudio. I'm assuming the base Eclipse release would behave the same way.

I've found what looks like two different places that could work, but neither yield any results:

```
ZendStudio.app\Contents\info.plist
ZendStudio.app\Contents\MacOS\ZendStudio.ini
```

Am I looking in the right place, or is this even possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you mean that you want to start Eclipse with some command line arguments, there is no file where you can add those to be used as default. But you can make a small script that will start Eclipse with the arguments you want, something like:

`/Applications/Eclipse.app/Context/MacOS/eclipse some command line arguments`

and then add executable permissions to your script, through Terminal window:

`chmod 755 your_file`

you can just type "`chmod 755` " on the terminal and then drag and drop the script file on the terminal window, it will type the file's full path onto it, press ENTER and that's it. You can double-click your script file and it will start up Eclipse with the command line arguments you typed.

Comment: `Context` in the path should be `Contents`